# Unable to show cn=config for ldap

Tags: ldap

I'm using OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 16.04.

My endgame is to use an LDAP directory as basis for a Samba 4 NT domain (legacy reasons).

When I run `slapcat`, I see all data that I have entered into the LDAP.

However, when I run `slapd` and execute

```
ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" -LLL -Q "olcDatabase=*"
```

my search yields "no such object (32)".

Why is that so? The configuration directory is clearly there under /etc/ldap/slapd.d/ and is being considered when running slapd.

I suspect it has something to do with authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can access a LDAP server is a matter of correct access control.

Normally you have to use *authz-regexp* directive to map the local user (e.g. *root*) to a authz-DN which is then granted access by  and *access to* directive(s) (see [slapd.conf](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.conf) static configuration).

See also: [OpenLDAP Admin Guide -- Access Control](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)